# Load HTML source code

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-xe3

How do I load HTML source code? I tried a few functions with no luck. This one works for me on many sites, but not all of them:

```
function LoadWebPageToString(MyUrl: String): String;  //load HTML content from a webpage to a string
begin
  Result := 'Error';
  with TIdHTTP.Create do
  begin
    try
      Result := Get(MyUrl);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

When it fails, I get this error:

> HTTP/1.1 403 forbidden

The target page is just a normal page. It loads normally via HTTP, doesn't require (think nor supports) HTTPS. Maybe it is about cookies or something? I don't know.

Comment: Try setting the useragent property like so . `Request.UserAgent:='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0';`

Comment: @RRUZ - Thank you, this worked. I didn't get error 403. Can you tell me one more thing: any idea how to get source from Facebook page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reasons of the `HTTP/1.1 403 forbidden` is which the server doesn't recognizes the user agent of the client, so try setting the `useragent` property like so .

```
Request.UserAgent:='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0';
```